# Lasagne - Why is the Validation Loss Highlighted Green?

Tags: python, neural-network, lasagne

I'm running the MNIST Neural Network example and when training the classifier, the Validation Loss column (and training loss) has some values highlighted in green. If i have the learning rate at 0.01, all are green, however if i increase it to 0.1, only half of them are highlighted.

What does this highlighting mean if anything?

Output example:
[image: Validation Loss Highlighting]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing the internals, i see a pattern there.

- Color each row as long as there is an improvement (minimization -> it's lower)

  - train-loss blue
  - val-loss green
- Stop coloring when loss / validation did increase

  - Don't start coloring again after this one-time increase

Different learning-rates will effect in different train-loss / val-loss paths and therefore some possible different coloring.

Your example fits well there, as a lower learning-rate is usually more stable (from iteration to iteration) in regards to lowering the loss (more blue, more green).